# Integration by substitution of a lineal function

Tags: integration, substitution

I notice that the integral of a linear function gives different results by using a method or another

Integrating directly,

\begin{equation}
  \int (a+bx) dx = ax+b\dfrac{x^2}{2} +c_1
\end{equation}

And making a substitution,
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \int (a+bx) dx &\\
    u=(a+bx) &\Rightarrow du=bdx \\
    \int u \dfrac{du}{b} = \dfrac{1}{b}\dfrac{u^2}{2} +c_2 &=\dfrac{a^2}{2b}+\dfrac{bx^2}{2}+ax
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

And comparing results, they are obviously not equal

\begin{equation}
  ax+b\dfrac{x^2}{2} +c_1 = ax +\dfrac{bx^2}{2} + \dfrac{a^2}{2b} +c_2
\end{equation}

My question is, how to explain that?
Is it simply  an arbitrary integration constants problem?

Comment: Yes, it just has to do with the constants.
$$c_1=c_2+\frac{a^2}{2b}$$

Comment: They're identical up to changing the constant. But an indefinite integral is only determined up to an arbitrary constant anyway, so that it appears to differ when using different techniques is basically irrelevant.